# testcafe firefox allow autoplay

Tags: javascript, firefox, automated-tests, testcafe, autoplay

I wrote some tests using **testcafe**. Their contents are not worth mentioning, I think.
Some of them rely on the browser's ability to automatically play audio.

**When I use *Chrome* to  run tests**:
`testcafe "chrome --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required" testfile.js`
everything works fine and audio on-page starts to play automatically.

**However, when I use *Firefox***:
`testcafe "firefox" test_widget.js`
autoplay is disabled and no audio is playing. If I add `--autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required` nothing really changes.

[image: autoplay disabled flag]

Checking available parameters from `firefox -h` gave no valuable result.

### Question:

**What should I do to allow autoplay in *Firefox* using it as a browser to run tests via *testcafe*?**

*Possible guesses:*

- some flag in command
- some code in test file

*Software vesions:*
`testcafe 1.7.0; Mozilla Firefox 71.0`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can allow autoplay using browser settings and launch Firefox with your current [user profile](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/common-concepts/browsers/user-profiles.html):

```
testcafe firefox:userProfile tests/test.js
```